# How to set expand submenu without active

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I used mary-ui with livewire-volt in laravel 10 project,but I dion't know how to set expand  to open by default.

```
            <x-menu-item title="xxxx" icon="o-building-storefront" link="/" />
            <x-menu-item title="xxxxx" icon="o-shopping-cart" link="/" />
            <x-menu-sub title="xxxxx" icon="o-cog-6-tooth"> // want to expand this without active.
                <x-menu-item title="xxxx" icon="o-wifi" link="####"  />
                <x-menu-item title="xxxxx" icon="o-archive-box" link="####" />
            </x-menu-sub>
```

set  expand by default without active in livewire-volt syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force it open with this special class placed on any children menu.

```html
class="mary-active-menu"
```

```html
<x-menu-sub title="Settings" icon="o-cog-6-tooth">
      <x-menu-item title="Wifi" icon="o-wifi" class="mary-active-menu" />
      <x-menu-item title="Archives" icon="o-archive-box" />
</x-menu-sub>
```

This is not documented because it is not a recommend approach. It really depends what design you intend with this.

Tip: Open a GitHub "question" issue, so more people can help you.
https://github.com/robsontenorio/mary

Answer (score 0):

I found solution but it's not beautiful. Can any one else solve it?

```
<script>
    let submenu = document.querySelector("summary")
    console.log(submenu);
     setTimeout(() => {
        submenu.click()
     }, 500);
</script>
```